# COUNT vs SELECT in SQL

Tags: sql, performance

What is better approach to check existence of an object in database?

```
select count(id) as count from my_table where name="searchedName";
```

**OR**

```
select id from my_table where name="searchedName";
```

And then check if `count > 0` or the object is not null (ORM logic)

**EDIT:**

`select id` to be valid for Oracle.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Those queries are product specific.

Comment: H2 in dev and Oracle in prod

Comment: `top 1` is not valid for Oracle.

Comment: You develope in H2, but production is Oracle? That's a very bad idea. Not every query that works in H2 works in Oracle too. (E.g. the standard SQL query 'select 1;' is invalid in Oracle.) Your queries are both invalid by the way; string delimiter is the single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea should be to that we only need to find *one* record in order to say that such record exists. This can be done with an `EXISTS` clause in standard SQL.

```
select exists (select * from mytable where name = 'searchedName');
```

returns true if the table contains a record with 'searchedName' and false otherwise.

If you want 0 for false and 1 for true instead (e.g. if the DBMS does not support booleans):

```
select case when exists (select * from mytable where name = 'searchedName') 
  then 1 else 0 end as does_exist;
```

You say you want this for Oracle. In Oracle you can use above query, but you'd have to select from the table `dual`:

```
select case when exists (select * from mytable where name = 'searchedName') 
  then 1 else 0 end as does_exist
from dual;
```

But for Oracle we'd usually use `rownum` instead:

```
select count(*) as does_exist
from mytable 
where name = 'searchedName'
and rownum = 1; -- to find one record suffices and we'd stop then
```

This also returns 1 if the table contains a record with 'searchedName' and 0 otherwise. This is a very typical way in Oracle to limit lookups and the query is very readable (in my opinion).

Comment: Although I like the answer, I still don't like the Oracle solution.  Using `count(*0` for this purpose just sends the wrong signal -- even with the `rownum = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just call:

```
select id from my_table where name='searchedName';
```

Making sure there is an index for the `name` column.
And then check whether or not the result is empty.

Comment: If you need to use the result logic for another SQL query, I'd go back to the back-end language (for instance Java or PHP) and then depending on the result, call another SQL query.

Comment: But if that's the case, you should also post that part of the SQL logic for us to optimize our answers (both queries could be combined)

Answer (score 0):

Try with IF EXISTS (

```
if exists (select 1 from my_table where name = "searchedName")
begin
     ....
end
```